# I want to apply JWT/OAuth2 in sails

Tags: sails.js, jwt

I am very new to sailsJs and have gone through few online resources for applying authentication on the apis that I want to build.Most of the tutorials are either outdated or is a overkill like applying passport because I would just want to apply authentication on api that too on selective routes.I would just need a direction to start working upon.Any help or suggestion is most welcomed.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I worked in Sails long ago, In order to have authentication, first of all you have to create Policies & then use it for specified controllers.

Comment: Thank you will look poliices up